# view .m files in a folder (including subFolders) in MATLAB

Tags: file, matlab, directory, subdirectory, dir

I have a Folder `Factors` inside `Project` folder.  (all inside MyDocuments/Matlab).  I need the list of all .m files in the folder FACTORS.  Factors has subFolders and these subFolders hold all the .m files.  Any suggestions?

Directory Design ->

```
Project...
    Factors ... etc
       subFol1 (has .m files)
       subFol2 (has .m files)
    ...
```

Comment: Do you use windows or matlab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved a similar problem.On Windows platforms, ,Like this:

```
pathName='.... \FACTORS';%your path
[stat path]=dos(['dir ' pathName '\*.m /s /B >path.txt'] );
name=importdata('path.txt');
delete path.txt
```

Now,you can see all files which matches the conditions is in the cell array "Name"

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://iheartmatlab.blogspot.com/2008/07/recursive-directory-function-execution.html) function would be useful. It will recursively search folders, executing a user defined function on each directory. You will need to write your own function to list all .m files in the current directory.