# load multiple specific folders from a directory in MATLAB/Extract file type from multiple different folders in a directory

Tags: matlab, loading, directory, extract

I am wondering how to load multiple specific folders from a directory in MATLAB.

Each of these specific folders, have sub-folders(all named the same), and within these subfolders are .mat files I need to extrapolate and compile.

Essentially, I just need to get the .mat files from the entire directory.

I can get the all .mat files from a folder, but don't know how to get *all* the .mat files from the main directory.

I realize I could use a script that loads each folder individually; essentially copying and pasting the same script for each folder and editing the variables.

However, it would be much more useful if I could just extract the .mat files from the entire directory.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [view .m files in a folder (including subFolders) in MATLAB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8673736/view-m-files-in-a-folder-including-subfolders-in-matlab)

Comment: which OS are you using?

Comment: Thanks erfan. Using ubuntu.